# Wanted: GUI interface to show status of services on many servers

Tags: rhel, services, monitoring, gui, html

We have 763 Red Hat 7.2 Linux machines with [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#), [systemctl](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) and the [presto](https://prestodb.github.io/) service:

```
 systemctl  status presto.service
● presto.service - Perforce Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/presto.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-06-25 18:30:22 UTC; 22min ago
```

We want a GUI to indicate all presto services, whether up or down. We can guarantee network-level remote access.

Please advise which applications,  GUI or HTML GUI, we can download and install to show the status of the presto service on each server.

Comment: ... across multiple machines? various operating systems?  init systems (SysV vs systemd)?

Comment: all machines are rehat 7.2 and use systemctl

Comment: This feels very broad to me. Whatever method you use will need to remotely query this status (or have the status pushed to it). Can you guarantee network-level remote access?

Comment: Can you guarantee network-level remote access?  - YES

Comment: the option of - bash <(curl -Ss https://my-netdata.io/kickstart.sh)  , is very huge , but since we not have network to my-netdata.io , then what is the option to install it , I mean first I need to download the pkg to the linux  and then to install it

Comment: @Yael, you can delete your Comments  above now they're added to the Question, to make room for other comments. Some other things to look at: 1) Cacti https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-rhel-install-cacti-monitoring-rrd-software/ 2) CheckMK https://checkmk.com/cms.html 3) Icinga https://icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest  4) Nagios https://nagios.org 5) Netdata https://github.com/netdata/netdata/blob/master/README.md 6) Promethius https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-prometheus-to-monitor-your-centos-7-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [presto-admin server status](https://github.com/prestodb/presto-admin/blob/master/README.md) on each node to generate a status report.
Query repeatedly each of your 763 nodes for that staus.
Sort the result on the node URL and throw away all but the latest status. 
Turn that into HTML with a script.
Generate an HTML page to display which might look something like this
[image] by perpetually refreshing an HTML page which draws on the status found from the server status reports: Green for Up, Yellow for No Report for X minutes, and Red for Down.

Also suggest you [read up here](http://cyberciti.biz/tips/top-linux-monitoring-tools.html) on some of the availability monitoring tools available to monitor hundreds of nodes

Comment: try check_mk. Its easy to setup across machines using an agent and has capability to send alerts. Dashboards can be setup for different views and it allows event handler for triggers.

Comment: please share link to mk

Comment: https://checkmk.com/cms.html